# E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.products index: name_1 dup key: { name: "tomek" }

Tags: mongodb, next.js

so the user who is 'logged in' want to buy a certain product. i want to send post request of that producuct to save it and then i basket i want to retrive (GET) it so that i can display it and do something with it. but i have this problem here what should i do ?

here is my code starting from models/Product.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const productSchema = new Schema(
  {
  id: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  unique: true,
},
name: {
  type: String,

  required: true,
},
email: {
  type: String,

  required: true,
},
category: {
  type: String,

  required: true,
},
title: {
  type: String,

  required: true,
},
price: {
  type: String,

  required: true,
},
},

  { timestamps: true }
);
```

next api/products/route.js

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Product from "@/models/Product";
import connect from "@/utils/db";

export const POST = async (request) => {
  const { id, name, email, category, title, price } = await request.json();

  await connect();

  const newProduct = new Product({
    id,
    name,
    email,
    category,
    title,
    price,
  });

  console.log(newProduct);
  try {
    await newProduct.save();
    return new NextResponse("Product has been landed", {
      status: 201,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return new NextResponse(err, {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
};
```

and finally last one, when user is authenticated then:

```
const id = Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 1000000);
      const name = session.data.user.name;
      const email = session.data.user.email;
      const category = current[0].category;
      const title = current[0].title;
      const price = current[0].price;

      try {
        const res = await fetch("/api/products", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },

          body: JSON.stringify({
            id,
            name,
            email,
            category,
            title,
            price,
          }),
        });

        res.status === 201 && console.log("essa");
        res.status === 500 && console.log("lipa");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Go check what the error log has to say, to find the _reason_ of the 500 error.

Comment: it says failed to load resources, internal server error 500

Comment: @tomaszM-dev: That's just the server telling the client that *an error* occurred on the server.  But it's not telling the client what that error *is*.  You need to find out what the error is before you can address it.  If the POST request to `/api/products` is producing an error then your next step is to debug the server-side code at `/api/products`.

Comment: _"it says failed to load resources,"_ - that sounds like something from the browser console. Your error happened on the server, so go check the logs there.

Comment: how can i do that ? on  api/products/route.js ?

Comment: @tomaszM-dev: If the HTTP 500 response is from that `catch` block on `route.js` then you'll want to log/observe that `err` value.

Comment: so my problem is when i send POST second time i get Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')     at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:277:61)

Comment: According to the title of the question, you have a unique index on the `name` field that seems to be incompatible with the current app logic. Either drop the index or modify the code to avoid/handle creating duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution, i checked every inch of my code looking for some bug but couldnt find any: i think the error was that in mongodb i changed data and deleted it many times and in collection/indexes i had several id's that where saved couple of times due to data changing that i did, to simplify:

i create data => created id automatically by mongodb to that data => i deleted that data because i made some changes in code (in post req) => but that index was still there and due to that this error was showing up

so the solution was to drop every index that i had there saved and let mongodb create new index based on current data from newest post request i found this solution on youtube and above there is my explanation to that problem its far from perfect but if anyone have some question im happy to help with that. i will link up this video below :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncHTczJs2dc&ab_channel=CStechware